# ASP.Net MVC Music Store Tutorial CSS Layout issue

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I just completed an [MVC tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1), but some of my webpages don't look right. This is mine: [image: Screenshot of my webpage]

But it's supposed to look like this:[image]

The code for this page is:

```
@model MvcSuper.Models.MusicStore.Genre

@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse Albums"; 
} 

<div class="genre"> 
    <h3><em>@Model.Name</em> Albums</h3> 

    <ul id="album-list"> 
        @foreach (var album in Model.Albums) 
        { 
            <li> 
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details",  
                    new { id = album.AlbumId })"> 
                    <img alt="@album.Title"  
                        src="@album.AlbumArtUrl" /> 
                    <span>@album.Title</span> 
                </a> 
            </li> 
        } 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

The left menu (partial view):

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcSuper.Models.MusicStore.Genre>
<ul id="categories"> 
    @foreach (var genre in Model) 
    { 
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(genre.Name, 
                "Browse", "MusicStore",  
                new { Genre = genre.Name }, null) 
        </li> 
    } 
</ul>
```

Entire CSS:

```
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}

body
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #FBF9EF;
    padding: 0px 6%;
}

#container
{
    float: left;
}

#header
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #5D5A53;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#header h1
{
    font-size: 18px;
    float: left;
    background: url(/content/Images/logo.png) no-repeat;
    padding: 45px 0px 5px 0px;
}

#promotion
{
    height: 300px; 
    width: 700px; 
    background: url(/content/Images/home-showcase.png) no-repeat;
}

ul li a
{
    font-size: 16px;
}

#main
{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 15px 10px;
    float: left;
}

ul
{
    list-style-type: square;
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

ul#album-list
{
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

ul#album-list li
{
    height: 130px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul#album-list li a, ul#album-list li .button
{
    font-size: 13px;
    float: left;
}

ul#album-list li a span
{
    color: #9b9993;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#cart
{
    float: right;
}

#update-message
{
    color: #F6855E;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.button, input[type=submit]
{
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px; 
    border: 1px;
    background: #5e5b54;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.button a
{
    color: #fff !important;
}

#footer
{
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    border-top: 1px dotted #8A8575;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #8A8575;
    font-family: Constantia, Georgia, serif;
}

/******************** Top Navigation ************************/
ul#navlist
{
    float: right;
}

ul#navlist li
{
    display: inline;
}

ul#navlist li a
{
    border-left: 1px dotted #8A8575;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #8A8575;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
}

ul#navlist li:first-child a
{
    border: none;
}

ul#navlist li a:hover
{
    color: #F6855E;
}

/********************* End top navigation ***************************/

p
{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

h2
{
    color: #5e5b54;
}

h2, h3
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h3
{
    color: #9B9993;
}

#header h1 a, h3 em
{
    color: #5E5B54;
}

a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #F6855E;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover
{
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:active
{
    color: #006633;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/***************************** sidebar navigation ****************************/

#categories
{
    font-family: Constantia, Georgia, serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-right: #5d5a53 1px dotted;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin: 0 25px 0 0;
    float: left;
}

#categories a:link, #categories a:visited
{
    color: #9B9993;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#categories a:hover
{
    color: #F46739;
}

div#album-details p
{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: #5e5b54;
    font-weight: bold;
}

p em
{
    color: #9b9993;
}

/* Form styles */
legend
{
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

fieldset
{
    border: #9b9993 1px solid;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    clear: left;
}

div.editor-field
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password], select
{
    border: 1px solid #8A8575;
    width: 300px;
}

/* Styles for validation helpers */
.field-validation-error {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}

/* Tables */
table
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: #666666;
    min-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

tr
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    line-height: 25px;
}

th
{
    background-color: #9b9993;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: left;
}

th, td
{
    padding-left: 5px;
}

tr:hover
{
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

I did download the source code (the author's finished version), and it turned out like mine when I ran it. The top most screenshot is from FF4 on XP, but it looks the same in IE8 on XP. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use firebug to examine html to see what is going on

Comment: You are not showing us the full story. What is the css class for genre? What is the html and css class for the genre list? At a guess I would say to float these left. The most helpful thing to do would be to provide a live example but failing that the complete relevant source code is desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To push that Album listing back up to its rightful place and put your mind at ease...

add a width to your main css class:

```
#main
{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 15px 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
}
```

also add a * to first css class

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: @Andrew - float left, right, whatever ;-> Glad you have it working - that tutorial is pretty good for trying out MVC3!

Answer (score 1):

Just take it easy. I'm pretty sure that this is the case of specific browser or some extra tricky css code, nothing more. Make sure you understand all the things that tutorial says and let the screen be as it is